# 3.5e Construct Customization

Tags: dnd-3.5e

This is my first post so please bear with me. I am a huge fan of Bethesda's Fallout 4 and had recently purchased the *Automatron* DLC. For those who do not know, Automatron has a feature in the settlement construction menu to build an automatron station to build and design robots. I want to incorporate a system into my campaign, where a mechanic, Maverick, sells upgrades to the robot(s) that my players can purchase that can be useful in many different situations. Some ideas for modifications I had included:
Neural Processor which can process human thoughts and acts as a core processor for the robot, Repeating crossbow hand, Specific weapon proficiency mods, Light mods, Task modulators so the robot can do a task that players may not be able to do (like disable a DC 25 trap when they have no points in disabling). Maximum 1 or 2 per robot. Somethings similar to those with a price range system. Overall, I'm asking if anyone knows how to set up a campaign vendor system similar to this, with its wide range of customization, and some modification ideas if anyone has any.

Thanks for reading and hope to hear your responses.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour], it's a useful introduction to the site. It's not quite clear what you're asking for at the moment. Please read [our guidelines for asking about house rules](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/6274/4398) and [edit] your question accordingly. And if you want to discuss RPG things in a less structured format, the [chat] is always open once you've got 20+ rep.